# GitHub REST API - Retrieve Specific Fields

Tags: rest, github

I am building a personal website which uses GitHub API to retrieve a list of changes to a specific file.

Here's the example URL:
https://api.github.com/repos/oxou/oxou.github.io/commits?path=/data/post/linux-install-wine-staging/index.md

Because I take huge caution to not use too much bandwidth for performance reasons, I would want to filter out specific fields that will actually be shown on the client-side, I would want a response similar to this:

```json
[
 {
  sha: "...",
  commit: {
   committer: {
    name: "...",
    date: "..."
   },
   message: "..."
  }
 },
 ...
]
```

Does the GitHub REST API provide such capability?